# Pandas -- Type error from Pivot

Tags: python, pandas

I have the data below.

[image]

I am trying to create a pivot table, with 'Profile ID' at the side, and 'Booking Type' as the column headers.

```
dfpivot=y.pivot_table(index='Profile Id', columns='Booking Type', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)
```

But I encounter the error below.

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Does anyone knows why?

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by converting 'Booking Type' column to string format.

Comment: Yes, it is right. You get that error because of change in datatypes.